Hartshorne Theorem 3.2 and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz
Consider this part of the proof of Theorem 3.2 in Hartshornes algebraic geometry:

Let $A(Y)$ be the affine ring of an affine variety $Y$. Then the
quotient field of $A(Y)$ is isomorphic to the function field $K(Y)$.
Now $A(Y)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, so $K(Y)$ is a
finitely generated field extension of $k$.

For the last claim, I would argue that since $A(Y)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, also $K(Y)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, since taking quotients inherits this property. Further, since $K(Y)$ is even a field itself, it is a finitely generated field extension of $k$.
However, consider the following variant of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz (e.g. Aityah,MacDonald Corollary 5.24)

Let $k$ be a field and $B$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If $B$ is
a field then it is a finite algebraic extension of $k$.

But the way I argued, $K(Y)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra which is also a field, therefore $K(Y)$ is an finite algebraic extension of $k$. But this is much more strict than just being a finitely generated extension, and actually $K(Y)$ is shown to have transcendence degree equal to $\text{dim }Y$. Consequently, there have to be an error in my argument or I am misunderstanding something here.

Your mistake is that "finitely generated field extension of $k$" $\neq$ "finitely generated $k$-algebra which is a field". When we speak of finitely generated fields, they need to be finitely generated as a field. When we speak of finitely generated algebras, they need to be finitely generated as an algebra. Your mistake is that you forgot the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Fld}_k \to \mathbf{CAlg}_k$, so to speak. (That's no surprise, nobody writes them down.)
Not every finitely generated field extension is finitely generated as an algebra. The standard example is $K(T)$, the function field of $\mathbb{A}^1_K$. Of course it is finitely generated as a field extension of $K$. But it is not a finitely generated $K$-algebra. As a $K$-algebra, it is generated by $T$ and all $1/f$ for irreducible polynomials $f$. This set is infinite, and it cannot be made into a finite one.

I know that being finitely generated does not imply being finite. However, the finiteness comes from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, and I do not see why this theorem is not applicable here. But I know that this result have to be wrong.

Is it clearer now?

Yes, thank you! But then I wonder, how to prove that $K(Y)$ is a finitely generated field extension of $k$?

If $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, which is an integral domain, say by the elements $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$, then guess how to get field generators of $Q(A)$ over $k$. There is only one possible answer, and that is the correct one, and the proof is one line.

Isn't $Q(A)$ as field also just generated by $a_1,..,a_n$ over $k$?
So $K(Y)$ is not a finitely generated $k$-algebra, but only a finitely generated field extension and therefore Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is not applicable.

Yes, that's correct.

Thank you very much. I appreciate your help on this!
